# Две пары двойных кавычек в json

Tags: php, json

Приходит мне от API такой вот json:

```
{"value\":\"г. Москва\/Общество с ограниченной ответственностью \\"Автостандарт-36\\"\"}
```

Функция `json_decode($result,true);` при таком исходе ломается, когда натыкается опять на кавычки, в которых значение - Автостандарт-36.

Пробовал заменять слеши вот так, но всё равно что-то не так.

```
$result = str_replace('\\"', ' ', $result);
```

как правильно отпарсить данные json?

Comment: Это не json, очевидно. Может лучше API починить?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, с чего вы так решили?

Comment: @AlexeyTen API не моё). И это json. В ответах, где нет двойных пар кавычек, то всё парсится норм функцией - json_decode

Comment: @Let'ssayPie с того, что json_parse падает, значит это не json, а какая-то похожая на него строка. Иногда, по счастливому совпадению, она неотличима от json-а, но программисту который писал API надо оторвать тентакли за такое.

Comment: `{"value\":` - Мне очень интересно как так получилось, что перед первой `"` - нет обратного слеша, а у второй - есть.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, это json, который неправильно сформирован. Ну API ужасное конечно. Но это json, обычно это происходит, когда применяется функция json_encode повторно

Comment: такой вопрос уже был, попробуйте поискать в поиске сайта (правда не помню точно на ru.so или en.so)

Comment: Мне кажется что "json, который неправильно сформирован" это автоматически __не__ json.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie API, которое Вы ругаете - разработка Департамента ИТ Москвы. С ним работать просто ужасно, первый раз вижу такой подход к разработкам гос. систем

Comment: @Manitikyl, в принципе, там все поля так сделаны. Вот кусок:  {\"response\":{\"statusCode\":0}}

Comment: @sbaikov, посмотрите, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
function fixed($json)
{
    return str_replace('`', '"', preg_replace(
            '/`([^`]+)`(?=`)/', 
            '\\\"$1\"', 
            str_replace(['\"', '"'], '`', $json))
    );
}

print_r(json_decode(fixed($json), true));
```

Comment: на выходе null - https://ideone.com/3WIstd

Comment: @Alex, обновил решение

Comment: И вам тоже поясню. Автор **уже видит** 2 слеша здесь: `\\"Автостандарт-36\\"`, ибо он написал(`Приходит мне от API такой вот json`). Ваш пример работает только с одним. Когда вы в переменной указываете 2 слеша, один уходит для экранизации, в итоге остается только один. Для примера: `echo '123\\123';` - выведет `123\123`

Answer (score 2):

Костыльный приход, костыльное решение:

```
$result = '{"value\":\"г. Москва\/Общество с ограниченной ответственностью \\\\"Автостандарт-36\\\\"\"}';
var_dump($result);
$result = str_replace('\"', '"', $result);
var_dump($result);
var_dump (json_decode($result,true));
```

Тогда, **входная строка:**

```
{"value\":\"г. Москва\/Общество с ограниченной ответственностью \\"Автостандарт-36\\"\"}
```

**После str_replace:**

```
{"value":"г. Москва\/Общество с ограниченной ответственностью \"Автостандарт-36\""}
```

**Результат:**

```
array(1) {
  ["value"]=>
  string(124) "г. Москва/Общество с ограниченной ответственностью "Автостандарт-36""
}
```

Comment: кстати, я так пробовал, не работает. Валидатор json в этом случае ругается вообще на каждую строку. Но если вторым параметром у str_replace указать пробел, то валидатор молчит, но json_decode всё равно ломается) В любом случае, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @Alex я специально указал **входная строка**. Дело в том что автор видит 2 слеша. Т.е. чтобы сымитировать такую строку, надо указать 4 слеша.

Comment: @Alex т.е. автор на экране уже видит `{"value\":\"г. Москва\/Общество с ограниченной ответственностью \\"Автостандарт-36\\"\"}`. А теперь вы возьмите свою строку и сделайте `echo` вы увидите что у вас будет всего лишь один слеш, что не соответствует.

Comment: @sbaikov что у вас ломается? на какой строке. нужны примеры, ибо тот что в впорсе должен работать. C `$result = '{\"response\":{\"statusCode\":0}}';` - тоже все работает

Comment: @Manitikyl я делаю echo и у меня: `\"value\":\"г. Москва\/Общество с ограниченной ответственностью \\"Автостандарт-36\\"\"` При последних двух var_dump -null

Comment: @sbaikov вы мне покажите полностью строку, которая вам приходите и не работает с моим способом, а не ее кусок.

Comment: @Manitikyl да, по слешам Вы правы)